# using like clause with peewee.Model.get method

Tags: peewee

```
class SomeModel(peewee.Model):
    date_time_added = peewee.DateTimeField()
```

date_time_added row contains datetime in the format "12-02-1982 18:12:22" format

i can get by building the select query

```
SomeModel.select(SomeModel.date_added).where(SomeModel.date_time_added.startswith("12-02-1982"))
```

how do I get time with specific date using get method of `peewee.Model
SomeModel.get`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off I'd like to *strongly* advise against using that format. Why? It doesn't sort properly. If you use YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS then you can do sorts and range scans and the results will actually be sensible.

With `.get()` you would:

```
obj = SomeModel.get(SomeModel.date_time_added.startswith('12-02-1982'))
```

Or alternatively:

```
query = SomeModel.select(SomeModel.date_added).where(SomeModel.date_time_added.startswith('12-02-1982'))
obj = query.get()
```